# How to read an image from desktop and input into a div tag?

Tags: html, css, image

I can't seem to get my image from my desktop and put it in one of my div tag. Can someone please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <img src="C:\Users\aldiaz\Desktop\DynamicsTest1.jpg">
        <div id="container" style="width:500px">
            <div id="header" style="background-color:#0000F8;">
                <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;"> Triton Subs</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="image" style="background-color:yellow;  height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
                <img src="C:\Users\aldiaz\Desktop\DynamicsTest1.jpg height:200px; width:100px;floatleft;">
            </div>
            <div id="content" style="background- color:#D7D7D7;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">Dear [FIRSTNAME] [LASTNAME],<br/> <br/>You have earned 5 videos and are ready to redeem.<br/><br/>Log into the Triton Submarines Experience now to choose your reward!
            </div>
            <div id="footer" style="background-color:#0000F8;clear:both;text-align:center;"> Trinto Sub Co
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use relative path. Also notice src for second img tag. You code will not work if uploaded on server. So better to create a folder 'images' in your root directory and use relative paths.

Comment: Possibly your web server does not have read access to the users desktop folder....

Comment: @Yusuf - You are not supposed to remove the question after it is answered. Other people might also benefit from seeing the question and its answers.

Comment: The question is clear, the people who are replying have no clue and closing it. He wants to update HTML div by selecting an image from his disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write:

```
<img src="C:\Users\aldiaz\Desktop\DynamicsTest1.jpg" style="height:200px;width:100px;float:left">
```

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML file is on your desktop, then use a RELATIVE file path, such as:

```
 <img src="images/DynamicsTest1.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers aren't supposed to let you access files on your computer like that (well, IE does, but it shouldn't).  It's considered a security vulnerability.  Even if it was allowed, no one else visiting that page would be able to see the image because they probably don't have a user named aldiaz on their computer, and even if they did, that image probably won't exist on *his* desktop.

If you are linking to the images locally while you are testing before uploading to your webserver, use relative URLs instead like the others have suggested.

Now if you are looking at previewing an image before a user uploads it, there are many fine tutorials out there on how to use the relatively new FileReader API:

http://html5doctor.com/drag-and-drop-to-server/